# Many errors after using dd to create bootable USB stick

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, error-handling

Yesterday I tried to create a bootable USB stick using

```
sudo dd if=[PATH TO YOUR .iso FILE] of=/dev/sd[THAT 1 LETTER]
```

Everything went well. Next day morning when I tried to start my system I've got error message after `BIOS` section. 
The error:

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced. 
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda1: UNEXOECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
           (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesysten on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
BusyBOX v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

After `fsck /dev/sda1` command I can see messages about broken `Inodes`. After that I can run my system, but I can't use any application installed by myself. Only `terminal` works. I can't even create a text file because of `Destanation is read-only` error. I tried to run few application in terminal. For example, after `xyz$ opera` I can see `Buss Error (core dumped)` message. I am getting this message after all commands, even `sudo apt-get autoclean` does not work. 
I don't know how to repair my system.

My actually system is `Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS`.
Here you have output of `sudo lsblk -f` command. I have used `Lubuntu 16.04`

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL             UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb    iso9660 Lubuntu 16.10 i386
│ 2016-10-12-19-57-58-00               /cdrom
└─sdb1 iso9660 Lubuntu 16.10 i386
  2016-10-12-19-57-58-00               
zram3                                                                 [SWAP]
zram1                                                                 [SWAP]
sr0                                                                   
loop0  squashf                                                        /rofs
sda                                                                   
├─sda2                                                                
├─sda5 swap                      d9768f8d-7bc2-4579-b96a-24351278b21a [SWAP]
└─sda1 ext4                      90f2499b-90b1-49b0-ab74-303d9f410c2f 
zram2                                                                 [SWAP]
zram0                                                                 [SWAP]
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Huh, I've `dd` Ubuntu ISOs to USB sticks many times and never had a problem.

Comment: `Everything went well` did you boot from the usb successfully?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to add something. To properly burn ISO I needed to umount the usb stick. I used command mount -u /PATH_Of_USB. Maybe I make mistake and missed something...

Comment: Please tell us the name of the iso file (Ubuntu version etc) and the output of the following command line, when booted from another (linux) system  with the USB stick plugged in, `sudo lsblk -f` Please edit your original question to post the result. This information will help us help you.

Comment: You booted from Lubuntu 16.10. This is a live drive. The other drive has an installed system with an ext4 partition and a swap partition. It makes me confused, that you made a USB stick from an iso file, and have problems with the installed system and its /dev/sda1 with the ext4 firle system. Please explain with more details what you did in order to get that error output.

Comment: Is there a problem (only) with the installed system? And you want help to fix it? Then boot from the live drive (with Lubuntu 16.10) and unmount the ext4 file system with `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and run the following command line in order to repair the ext4 file system, `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda1`

Comment: So, from the beginning. I have read tutorial about `dd`command. As i said, I checked which number of `sda` is my `usb stick` then I used `mount - u` command. Thats all. After reboot i can't do noting on my computer.

Comment: I don't think that dd created the ext4 partition /dev/sda1, and doing what you did *should* not cause the problem you have. Maybe unplugging without unmounting caused the problem.

Comment: I didn't mount my USB Stick. Immediately after plugged I have unmounted  the usb stick. Maybe i make mistake and I unplugged other partition? I think that is possible because I used root privileges.

Comment: Please try to fix the ext4 file system according to a previous comment, and if you want more details, the following link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986 Scroll down to 'Repair linux file systems with linux tools'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56189/discussion-between-sudodus-and-konraddos).